# How to fix programming error when using pg8000 module to read_Sql

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services

Hi I'm trying to query  a table in aws redshift  into a pandas dataframe using a glue job . I am using pg8000 to connect ( as sqlalchemy is not supported in aws glue).

When i used using read_sql or read_sql_query function of pandas to query the table, i am getting extra char in dataframe which i guess is problem with pg8000 dbapi

```
conn = pg8000.connect(user = 'postgres', password = '*****', host =127.0.0.1,  port = 5439, database = 'lifungdb')

cursor = conn.cursor()
df=pd.read_sql("select * from Customer",conn)
print(df)
```

print (df) is returns with exta char b in the columns. How to strip that extra char

```
b'id'  b'Name' b'Address' b'Contact
 1       Sam     Texas       na
```

Comment: `df.str.decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @DirtyBit throws AttributeError: 'DataFrame' has no attribute str

Comment: see the answer I posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `list-comprehension` to decode the `utf-8` strings:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['1', 'sam', 'Texas', 'na']]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[b'id', b'Name', b'Address', b'Contact'])
df.columns = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in df.columns]
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
  id Name Address Contact
0  1  sam   Texas      na
```